# Nerdtree and current directory using vi from home folder

Tags: vi, nerdtree

How can I achive this situation:

1. Open vi in my home folder.
2. Navigate with NERDTree somewhere
3. Write :!ls and see the list of the directory in that I am with NERDTree

Comment: voting to migrate to superuser

Answer (score 0):

You can open a folder by typing 'e', this will change your current folder. But i'm not sure this is what you're looking for.